Can a Cell in Cellular Automata affect other Cells' states in its neighborhood?
Cell itself definitely get affected by other cells in its neighborhood and it may change its state accordingly. My question is that can a Cell affect other cells based on cells' states in its neighborhood? I am trying to represent movement of particles.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

if a cell gets affected by the cells around it, does that not answer your question?

For a CA rule to be well defined, we need it to unambiguously determine the state of each cell on the next time step, given the states of all the cells on the previous time step.
The usual way to ensure this is to write the rule in the form $$s_{t+1}(x) = f(s_t(x), N_t(x))$$ where $s_t(x)$ is the state of cell $x$ at time $t$, $N_t(x)$ is something that depends (solely) on the states of cells in some local "neighborhood" of cell $x$ at time $t$, and $f$ is a function that maps the current state and neighborhood of a cell to its next state.
As you've noted, however, writing the rule in this form can make it difficult to construct cellular automata that e.g. conserve the number (but not the position!) of cells in certain states, like you might want to use e.g. to model the movement of particles on a lattice.
One traditional solution to this problem have been block cellular automata, developed in the 1970s and 1980s to study lattice gases and other interacting particle models.
In these automata, instead of the rule defining the next state of each individual cell separately, the lattice is instead partitioned into "blocks" (e.g. 2×2 squares) of cells, with the rule then mapping the current states of all cells within a block to the states of all those cells in the next time step.
Of course, on its own this would result in a rather boring automaton, since the update rule is applied to each block separately without the blocks interacting in any way. The remaining "magic ingredient" is that the block boundaries are changed on each time step, so that cells that used to be in separate blocks on the previous time step can end up in the same block on the next time step. In this way, signals can propagate from block to block through the entire lattice.
A block-based update rule makes it very easy to implement conservation laws. For example, for a block CA rule to conserve particle count, it is sufficient to ensure that the next state of each block contains the same number of particles as the previous state.
It's worth noting that block CA are not fundamentally distinct from ordinary CA: in particular, any block CA can be emulated by a "normal" CA, using an update rule of the form given at the beginning of this answer, with a sufficient number of states and a sufficiently large neighborhood. Writing the rule in the block-based form just makes it easier to construct rules with features like the conservation of particle number.
(Figuring out how to implement such emulation can be a nice exercise. One helpful trick is to first modify the block CA rule so that, instead of the block boundaries changing between time steps, the cells are moved between adjacent blocks after each time step. Then define a new CA rule whose cells correspond to the blocks of the original block CA rule, with enough states per cell to encode every possible state of a block in the original rule.)

That seems correct. Can you tell me how they are representing movements in these papers: Paper-1 and Paper-2. They did not mention exactly how they are representing it. They just use lattice.

The first paper you linked (of which I found a PDF copy at https://www.academia.edu/115435208/Cellular_Automaton_Models_for_Collective_Cell_Behaviour) seems to be using some variant of the Morita–Harao partitioning scheme, where each block (or "macrocell") contains multiple "microcells" for particles moving in different directions, and the update rule is a combination of a migration step (moving particles between adjacent blocks in their direction of motion) and a within-block interaction step (which can e.g. change the directions of particles depending on other particles in the same block).

… A nice feature of the Morita–Harao scheme (original paper archived here) is that emulating it with a "traditional" CA is trivial: just treat each block of microcells as a single traditional CA cell, with enough states per cell to encode all the possible combinations of microcell states.

… The second paper you linked seems to be using some kind of a ad hoc stochastic scheme to resolve collisions between moving particles, and without seeing their code I'm not sure how they deal with chains of collisions (where two particles colliding might cause one of them to stop and collide with another particle as a result). They might be doing something similar to the algorithm I described in this answer on gamedev.SE, but there are other ways they could handle it too.

… In any case, the model in the second paper looks more like an interacting particle system on a lattice than something I'd describe as a cellular automaton. Of course there is some overlap between the two concepts, but calling their model a CA feels a bit like trying to shoehorn it into a box that it doesn't really fit into.

Ps. I noticed that there's a Wikipedia article on "BIO-LGCA" that seems to do a pretty good job of describing the kind of model used in the first paper you linked. You might find it useful.
